# MessageBox dependent on value being a multiple of another value

Tags: excel, vba

I want a pop up message saying "Please Check" on input of a number in range (G24:G73) that is not a multiple of a number in the corresponding cell in column F (F24:F73).

In other words, I want a pop up message if Cell("F24") is 5, and  Cell("G24") is a number that is not 5, 10, 15, 20, 25......

How to code this using the MOD function?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("G24").value <> ? ? ? 
        MsgBox "Please Check UOM quantity"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `if target.value mod target.offset(0, -1).value <> 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is called the `mod` operator.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G24:G73")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target Mod Target.Offset(0, -1) <> 0 Then
          MsgBox "Please Check UOM quantity"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works good but when I select more than one cell on Range("G24:G73") delete the data, I get Run-time error '13' Type Mispatch, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There are many ways to handle that. Do a count of target and branch into it. Or do a loop `for each cel in target` to handle each row on its own.

Comment: Thanks, I just added in an `On Error GoTo` to go to `End Sub`

Comment: @UnEvenBolt That would be the absolute worst way to do it. It makes sure it's now possible to work around your restriction. E.g. by selecting G24:G30, typing in something wrong and pressing Ctrl+Enter.

Comment: @GSerg I did not realize that... How should I write in code so that I can avoid this??

Comment: As I said, do a loop and process each row on its own.